# C# Regex with words including asterisks

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to split the following string: `"'aaa bbb' 0.05 ccc 3* 20*0.1"`

so that the elements are:

```
0: aaa bbb
1: 0.05
2: ccc
3: 3*    
4: 20*0.1
```

I then want to loop over each of the results.  The following snippet handles the first 3 elements, but not the last two:

```
Regex
    .Matches(input, @"(?<match>[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)|(?<match>\w+)|'(?<match>[\w\s]*)'")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups["match"].Value)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(z => etc...
```

What should I add to the regex so that 3* and 20*0.01 are returned as single matches?

Comment: Almost any special character is regex can be escaped with a backslash. So, `*` would become `\*` if you wanted to literally refer to it. EDIT: Also, what's wrong with `(?<match>\d\*\s\d+\*\d\.\d)`?

Comment: Can you please describe more about the expected constraints?  Is '0.05*' valid?  'a5'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression matches the expressions the way you wanted:

```
foreach (var s in Regex.Matches("'aaa bbb' 0.05 ccc 3* 20*0.1", @"('[^']*'|\S+)")) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

produces this output:

```
'aaa bbb'
0.05
ccc
3*
20*0.1
```

All you need to do is detecting if a value has single quotes around it, and unquote if necessary.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  And thanks to everyone else for the other answers too.

Answer (score 0):

The following will match all 5:

```
@"(?<match>[-+]?\d*\*(\d+\.?\d*)?)|(?<match>[-+]?\d+\.?\d*)|(?<match>\w+)|'(?<match>[\w\s]*)'")
```